# Why does my credit card company want me to update my income on their website?

Tags: credit-card

They've already given me a card, which I pay off every month.  Why are they interested in how much I make?

Comment: Probably for marketing purposes.

Comment: Why not?  It's a general best practice to "know your customer"

Comment: Has something changed on your credit report recently?  Did you get a new car loan or different credit card or mortgage or something?  They may be internally reassessing your creditworthiness, either to market new products to you or adjust your limits.

Comment: @quid - I paid my car loan off.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason for an income check, beyond marketing purposes would be a credit limit increase. If you didn't apply for one, then it is most likely that they just want to keep their information on you up to date in order to mine better marketing data from you.

That is to say, if your income has changed, and your spending patterns change, they can use this data to get a better picture for their demographic marketing.

Comment: Is it in my best interest to tell them, or to ignore them?

Comment: There is a chance that if you don't tell them they could remove your credit, for some sort of non-compliance reason. If you are skeptical of telling them, try calling customer service and inquiring the exact reason they want the information. They should tell you, from there you can make a judgement call.